# How to retrieve the very last row (empty or not) of a Google Sheet by script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to prepare a Google Sheet for being printed partially. So I have to hide the unused rows at the bottom:

```
lastUsedSheetRow = ownSheet.getLastRow();
LastSheetRow = ownSheet.XXXXX()?;
ownSheet.hideRows(lastUsedSheetRow + 1 , LastSheetRow - lastUsedSheetRow + 1);

//hideRows(<index of first row to hide>, <number of rows to hide>);
```

What do I have to do to get the "veryLastSheetRow" of a sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)

> Returns the current number of rows in the sheet, regardless of content.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
ownSheet.getMaxRows()
```